# Percent encoding urls in xml nodes

Tags: xml, parsing, url, encoding, request

**What are the encoding considerations for URLs contained in XML nodes?**

For example `<node>http://www.something.com?key=some!wierd#value@</node>`. I'm wondering if the url should be percent encoded in the xml. Or perhaps this is better left to the code that parses and ultimately requests the url.

Comment: +1 I am seeing linq2xml not parsing this .net

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It shouln't make a difference unless the language that parses the url uses those symbols in certain ways. I don't know of any languages that use any of those symbols, but I don't know what language you are using.

Percent engoding uses, in theory, less symbols, so has less chance of meaning something else to the language, so you might aswell.

Have you seen [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding)?